Stuck in initramfs after editing etc/fstab
After updating to Ubuntu 22.04 in my DualBoot setup. I got stuck in Recovery mode with warning . In debugging process tried to edit the content of /etc/fstab, but this just worsen the things as I am currently stuck initramfs.
The Boot starts with bunch of following warnings:
failed to validate module nvme_core BTF -22
BFF: # type_id 118718 bits_offset=448
BFF:
BFF: Invalid name
BFF:

Then it ends up with:
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
ALERT! UUID=d379-xxx does not exist dropping to a shell!

Output of cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-generic root=UUID=d379-xxx ro quiet splash

Output of cat /proc/modules
crc32_pclmul 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc01a00000000 (E)
xhci_pci_renesas 2048 0 - Live 0xfffffffc028f00000. (E)
pinctrl_cannonlake 36864 0 - Live 0xffffffc023f00000 (E)

I wanted to try to modify boot params according to this post, but I dont know which dev number I should use and how to modify the boot params as /proc/cmdline seems to be read only.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-to-fix-boot-into-initramfs-prompt-and-mount-cant-read-etc-fstab-no-su
The dev directory contains only /dev/mapper, not any sda or nvme devices.
Output from dmesg | grep -i 'nvme|error'
pcieport  0000:00:1b.0: DPC: error containment capabilities Int Msg , Rpext+, PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PID Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
integrity: Error adding keys to platform keyring UEFI:db
RAS: Corractable Errors collector initalized
failed to validate module [nvme_core] BTF -22

I am really noob with this topic and I would appreciate any help. In this point I would be grateful to get at least to shell of my Ubuntu to backup my files and reinstall the system from scratch.
